# SAWarning: At least one scoped session is already present

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have purposefully defined 2 different engines (using the same DB URL) meant for 2 sessions with different configuration, Pyramid's `model.py`:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

DBSessionTask = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(), expire_on_commit=False))
```

Configuring sessions (in Pyramid app's main `__init__.py`):

```
engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine

engine_task = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
DBSessionTask.configure(bind=engine_task)
```

The sessions are meant to be used for 2 different categories of objects (`DBSessionTask` for long-running supervision objects kept in the app-wide settings, `DBSession` for typical scoped session on "data" objects of a web app).

I'm getting a warning:

```
sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py:99: SAWarning: At least one scoped session is already present.  configure() can not affect sessions that have already been created.
  warn('At least one scoped session is already present. '
```

Those are 2 different engines, so why SQA is warning me about it? They're using the same DB url of course, but why should that be a problem?

Comment: Why don't you want to use 1 `scoped_session`?

Comment: @matino: because one scoped session is regular Pyramid session, I don't want to muck with it like change its expire_on_commit setting. At the same time I need another session with this setting set to True.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple sessions in Pyramid+SQLAlchemy, you should  manage them explicitly instead of relying on scoped sessions. The scoped session sessionmaker expects to make one session per thread, hence your issues. Many pyramid devs prefer doing this anyway as a general rule as it fits well with the pyramid philosophy of passing everything through the request and context objects.  My preference is to make a db engine component that has a method for getting and closing the session, and register this component through the configurator. Then I have a custom request factory that creates the db session at the beginning of the request and commits or rolls it back at the end. You can do the same without a custom request factory too by registering request lifecycle callbacks in your configurator section. Here is an example of doing the above, taken from the cookbook, which you could adapt for multiple engines easily enough:

http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database/sqlalchemy.html

```
# __init__.py

from pyramid.config import Configurator
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def db(request):
    maker = request.registry.dbmaker
    session = maker()

    def cleanup(request):
        if request.exception is not None:
            session.rollback()
        else:
            session.commit()
        session.close()
    request.add_finished_callback(cleanup)

    return session


def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')
    config.registry.dbmaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    config.add_request_method(db, reify=True)
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning when running tests locally - is there a "one-obvious" way around this? The test DB is a temporary SQLIte file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one scope session binding your models to different database engines instead.